# how to disable the touchesbegan function for specific views (named as "sideV1" & "sideV2") click in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

on sideV1 & sideV2 touch it should not get hide, while we click else anywhere both sideV1 & sideV2 should be hidden,I am using touches began function to hide sideV1 & sideV2 while touch any where except click on sideV1 & sideV2.

Comment: Please share more for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

make tag for sideV1 and sidev2

```
sideV1.tag=randomTag1
 sideV2.tag=randomTag2
```

and on touch began check if touch view is sideV1 or sideV2 by getting tag of view pass to touch began and if tag matched then return

```
override  func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {

            if touch.view.tag == randomTag1 || touch.view.tag == randomTag2   {
               return
            }

  }
```